# Programmatically add text to the clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to programmatically add text to the clipboard in C# (3.5) or javascript ? Does the client machine type make a difference?

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention am using asp.net.

Comment: You indicate javasript in your tags. Do you mean for a webform, or a winform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware in the web world it would be a security issue to access the clipboard without some sort of client side control, i.e. ActiveX control or Flash. So it would prompt for the user to allow the access. [Here is something](http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/copyToClipboard/) to get you started.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Clipboard.SetText(string)` and `Clipboard.GetText()` to interact with the clipboard.

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx)

As long as the client supports .NET, it shouldn't make a difference.

---

Oh, for the web...

Then use something like this jQuery plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

It will allow you to copy and paste from the clipboard across browsers.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention am using asp.net

Comment: Not going to downvote because he mentioned ASP.NET after the initial question, but `ClipBoard.Set/GetText` will get and set the clipboard text on the *server*, and thus are unlikely to be useful

Answer (score 2):

C#: In System.Windows.Forms you have a Clipboard class and a [SetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k.aspx) method which probably is what you're looking for. Example:

```
Clipboard.SetText("My text");
```

**Edit:** Since you're looking for a way to set clipboard text on a client computer, here's an updated answer:

There is no browser agnostic way of setting clipboard text. It's possible in Internet Explorer using the following snippet:

```
window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'Your text');
```

In Firefox and Webkit browsers, for security reasons, you need to go via flash to set clipboard text. [Zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) is a nice library for this.

Comment: @hunter Read the question please. He clearly states that he wants a C# **OR** Javascript solution.

Comment: I don't think he wants winforms, but I removed my down vote anyway

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms there is a static Clipboard class with a SetText method. So you can use

```
Clipboard.SetText("whatever");
```

There are some differences to the default text format based on which operating system you are running on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[You can use Flash](http://randomfoo.net/2009/01/13/clipboard-copying-in-flash-10).